# Using VB how do I split and remove an @ from a log file?

Tags: vb.net, split

I have `username@usercomputer` in a log file. I am able to create the `DataGridView` table, but now I want to separate and remove the `@` and put the 2 in their own column. Any help would be very appreciated.

This is how the original data shows up:

> 7:13:19 (xW_D) OUT: "product" user@computername

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
' 3 other columns here
dt.Columns.Add("Product", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("User_Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("@", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("Computer_name",Type.GetType("System.String"))
```

I was able to Split the " " but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the @ as well. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Look into the `Split Function` here: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx** For example: `Dim TestArray() As String = Split(TestString, "@")`

Comment: How does the datasource structure for the datagridview look?

Comment: this is how the original data shows up
7:13:19 (xW_D) OUT: "product" user@computername
Dim dt As New DataTable()
       ' 3 other columns here
        dt.Columns.Add("Product", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("User_Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("@", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("Computer_name",Type.GetType("System.String"))
and I was able to Split the " " but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the @ as well. Thanks for looking

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..
it was in the 4th spot on the datatable so i split it there; 
Dim userComp() As String = split(4).Split("@")
'and created 2 more columns
dt.Rows.Add(split(0), split(2), split(3), split(4), userComp(0), userComp(1))